# Can you inline a bundler compiled script with NextJS SSR?

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

In my NextJS app, I have the need for javascript to run as soon as the HTML markup is hydrated (specifically before the first contentful paint).

I know that I can inline a `<script>` tag like this and get my code to run as soon as the browser parses the DOM:

```js
// In app.tsx

<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `<script type="text/javascript">console.log('hello');</script>`,
  }}
/>
```

Thats cute, but the actual code is a little more complex and would benefit from being separated into a few files.

Is there any way to define a separate entrypoint bundle to inline with NextJS? Or do I need to compile it myself and use a webpack replace plugin to swap it in after the build completes?

```js
<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `<script type="text/javascript">__ENTRYPOINT_2_BUNDLE__</script>`,
  }}
/>
```

If I could make up my own API, it might look like this:

```js
<Script type="inline-bundle" entrypoint="/bundles/ssr/index.js" />
```